# How to make Checkout button initialize paypal pay form ? ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, paypal, asp.net-core-3.1

I've been searching a solution for this problem and only found that you cannot target paypal buttons with jquery for security reasons.

So I have this form that i need to open my paypal window pay with cards and on success it should fire up an api call that I'll add later

```
<form onsubmit="openPaypal" style="margin-bottom:30px">
                <div class="row heading">
                    <h5>Checkout information</h5>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <div class="price-field">
                        <span><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input required name="email" type="email" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space"></div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <div class="price-field">
                        <span><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></span>
                        <input required name="name" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space"></div>
                <div class="field">
                    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And I need it to somehow when submitted , to open the paypal pay form.

I copied the paypal buttons solution from their docs

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ClientId">
    // Replace YOUR_SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID
</script>



<!-- Add the checkout buttons, set up the order and approve the order -->
<script>
    function openPaypal(event) {
        $('.paypal-button-number-1').click();
    }
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '0.01'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Display payment options on your web page
</script>
```

To be specific , I seek something like sellfy.com's paypal checkout. You enter your credentials in the cart , it makes a validation and then sends you to some paypal web page. There you enter what paypal needs and at the end you have return to merchant, where you get redirected to your website(in that redirect I guess you can call out a method that does the next part of the checkout)

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, so

```
function openPaypal(event) { 
    paypal.Buttons({
        [..snip..]
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
}
```

And since you want it to "fire up an API call", you should be creating and capturing the payment on the server side.  For that you need this UI button code: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

And two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: I need it to open the pop-up window form , not show the buttons.

Comment: To be specific , I seek something like sellfy.com's paypal checkout. You enter your credentials in the cart , it makes a validation and then sends you to some paypal web page. There you enter what paypal needs and at the end you have return to merchant, where you get redirected to your website(in that redirect I guess you can call out a method that does the next part of the checkout)

Comment: You could render the button immediately and use its onClick method to run whatever JS you want before opening the PayPal checkout